# Python: ftplib: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Tags: python, ftplib

I maintain a script running on a system that previously did not throw this exception. A new firmware version is causing this exception being raised. The nlist and retrlines functions for instance worked previously, and now are throwing the exception. I have tried using multiple different path representations and so on. There are open questions for  [Errno 11004], but not  [Errno 11001]. I have tried the solutions for the other related questions with no luck. Thank you!

```
>>> from ftplib import FTP
>>> ftp = FTP('192.168.1.11')
>>> ftp.login('username', 'password')  # actual credentials replaced for code sample...
'230 User logged in, proceed'
>>> ftp.nlst()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\some_user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\ftplib.py", line 557, in nlst
    self.retrlines(cmd, files.append)
  File "C:\Users\some_user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\ftplib.py", line 466, in retrlines
    with self.transfercmd(cmd) as conn, \
  File "C:\Users\some_user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\ftplib.py", line 397, in transfercmd
    return self.ntransfercmd(cmd, rest)[0]
  File "C:\Users\some_user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\ftplib.py", line 359, in ntransfercmd
    source_address=self.source_address)
  File "C:\Users\some_user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socket.py", line 704, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Users\some_user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socket.py", line 743, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
>>> ftp.retrlines('LIST')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\some_user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\ftplib.py", line 466, in retrlines
    with self.transfercmd(cmd) as conn, \
  File "C:\Users\some_user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\ftplib.py", line 397, in transfercmd
    return self.ntransfercmd(cmd, rest)[0]
  File "C:\Users\some_user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\ftplib.py", line 359, in ntransfercmd
    source_address=self.source_address)
  File "C:\Users\some_user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socket.py", line 704, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Users\some_user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socket.py", line 743, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
>>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the new firmware included a new TCP/IP stack (which included a new FTP implementation). This new implementation turns out did not support passive mode. I had to turn off passive mode off, which in FTPLIB is enabled by default. Once I did that, everything worked correctly.

```
        ftp = FTP(client.host)
        ftp.login(self.username, self.password)
        ftp.set_pasv(False)  # bingo :)
```